# Updating JSON Object in Mongodb using spring boot

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

Suppose I have a JSON Object which needs to be updated in Mongodb like

```
{
  "_id": 12345,
  "Attribute": { "Property1": "X", "Property2": true, "Property3": 123 }
}
```

Suppose I have a record in mongoDb

```
{
    "_id": 12345,
    "Attribute1": "abc",
    "Attribute2": "xyz",
    "Attribute": { "Property4": "X", "Property2": false, "Property3": 456 }
}
```

The result should update Attribute JSON while updating only the fields that are changed and keeping rest of the values intact.
Resultant record in db should be like this

```
{
    "_id": 12345,
    "Attribute1": "abc",
    "Attribute2": "xyz",
    "Attribute": { "Property4": "X", "Property1": "X", "Property2": true, "Property3": 123 }
}
```

I really don't know how to achieve this in single Pass in Mongodb using JAVA spring boot. Can Anyone please help? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Simple "$set" will do the intended job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved this using this query.

```
db.collection.update(
    {
      _id: 12345
    },
      {
        $set: {
              
                "Property1": "X", 
                "Property2": true, 
                "Property3": 123 
               }
            
      },
      {upsert: true}
     )
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Update class from org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query package. You can write a code snippet like below.

```
Update updateAttribute = new Update();
      updateAttribute.push("Attribute", "Your Value");
      mongoOperations.updateFirst(new Query(Criteria.where("id").is(12345)), updateAttribute, "yourCollection");
```

Also, you need to inject constructor for MongoOperations from org.springframework.data.mongodb.core package.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in 2 ways,

1. For Mongo version 4.4+ you can use [pipelined updates](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/), this allows the use of aggregation operators in the update body, specifically we'll want to use [$mergeObjects](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/mergeObjects/), like so:

```
db.collection.update(
{
  _id: 12345
},
[
  {
    $set: {
      Attribute: {
        $mergeObjects: [
          "$Attribute",
          {
            "Property1": "X",
            "Property2": true,
            "Property3": 123
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/1n3YdPqdVN5)

2. For lesser Mongo versions you'll have to construct the update body in code, here is a javascript example ( might be slightly more annoying in spring )

```
const input = {
    '_id': 12345,
    'Attribute': { 'Property1': 'X', 'Property2': true, 'Property3': 123 },
};

const updateBody = {};
Object.keys(input.Attribute).forEach((key) => {
    const updateKey = `Attribute.${key}`;
    updateBody[updateKey] = input.Attribute[key];
});
db.collection.updateOne({ _id: 12345 }, { $set: updateBody });
```

By using the dot notation in the update body we ensure we don't overwrite existing fields in the `Attribute`.

Comment: Thanks for this, but a simple "$set" will also work.

Comment: It is a simple set.